# Java Frames disposal creates extra empty frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

I am making a simple login application, but every time i press a button to open another frame(From another class) i get an extra empty frame for some reason.
I tried testing it by writing a new class and connecting it to another button.. that class just had JFrame.. and it would still give me another empty frame.

Code

```
package application;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class MainScreen extends JFrame{
    private JFrame frame;// frame of the interface
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel left = new JPanel();
    private JPanel center = new JPanel();
    private JPanel top = new JPanel();
    private JButton approve = new JButton("Approve");
    private JButton review = new JButton("Review");
    private JButton employmentCreate = new JButton("Create/Modify");
    private JLabel PR = new JLabel("Personal Records");
    private JLabel ER = new JLabel("Employment Records");
    private JLabel PerR = new JLabel("Perform Review");
    private JLabel AR = new JLabel("Approve Records");
    private JLabel news = new JLabel("There are no news");
    private JLabel empty = new JLabel();
    private JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
    private JButton personalCreate = new JButton("Create/Modify");
    private JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Welcome:");
    private JLabel userLbl = new JLabel("USERNAME GOES HERE");

    public MainScreen()
    {
        makeFrame();
    }
    private void makeFrame()
    {
       frame = new JFrame("Main Screen");  
       frame.setSize(650,550);
       frame.setResizable(false);
       makeMenuBar(frame);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
       //makes application start in the center of the screen
       Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
       frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);
       //border
       UIManager.getDefaults().put("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.BLACK);
       Border lowerEtched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);
       TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lowerEtched, "Main Screen");
       Font titleFont = UIManager.getFont("TitledBorder.font");
       title.setTitleFont( titleFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD) );
       panel.setBorder( title );
       //border end
       frame.setVisible(true);  
       frame.add(panel);
       panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       panel.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
       top.add(welcome);
       top.add(userLbl);
       panel.add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
       left.add(news);
       panel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));
       center.setLayout( new GridLayout(5,2));
       center.add(PR);
       center.add(personalCreate);
       personalCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            frame.dispose();
            PR pr = new PR();
            pr.setVisible(true);
        }
         });
       center.add(ER);
       center.add(employmentCreate);
       employmentCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            frame.dispose();
            ER er = new ER();
            er.setVisible(true);
        }
         });
       center.add(PerR);
       center.add(review);
       center.add(AR);      
       center.add(approve);
       center.add(empty);
       center.add(logout);

       //border
       UIManager.getDefaults().put("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.BLACK);
       TitledBorder title2 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lowerEtched, "News");
       Font title2Font = UIManager.getFont("TitledBorder.font");
       title.setTitleFont( titleFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD) );
       left.setBorder( title2 );
       //border end



    }
     /**
     * Receive notification of an action.
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Menu item: " + event.getActionCommand());
    } 

    /**
     * Quits the application.
     */
    private void quit()
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
       /**
     * About pop up.
     */
    private void about()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                    "Group Project Application",
                    "About Application",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    /**
     * Restarts the application
     */
    private void restart()
    {
       frame.dispose();
        makeFrame();
    }
      /**
     * Creates the main frame's menu bar with menu items.
     */
    private void makeMenuBar(JFrame frame)
    {
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        JMenu menu;
        JMenuItem item;

        // create's File menu
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(menu);
        //restart application
        item = new JMenuItem("Restart");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { restart(); }
         });
        menu.add(item);
        //quit button
        item = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { quit(); }
         });
        menu.add(item);       

        //create's About menu
        menu= new JMenu ("Help");
        menubar.add(menu);

        item = new JMenuItem("About");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { about(); }
        });
        menu.add(item);

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't not comment on `catch(Exception ex){}`. Please, please just don't do this. Please.

Comment: Regarding your actual problem, I can't find the source in your code posted and suspect that it may be due to code not posted. It's likely time for you to do some debugging to try to isolate your error. Also, consider creating smaller more testable classes, so that you can test each class simply and in isolation. Also you'll want to improve your code formatting so that it will be easier for you (and for **us**) to understand your code structure and flow, and to find bugs.

Comment: By the way, what does this Application super class do? It doesn't create a and display JFrame, does it?

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply.. i will post application class.

Comment: About Exception ex.. do you mean i shoul use SQLException?

Comment: You should catch the most specific exception possible, and you should never ignore the exception as you're doing. This is a programming equivalent to driving with your eyes closed.

Comment: so how would i write it?

Comment: Read a tutorial on use of exceptions for starters, something Google should help you find. Then do something with the exception in the catch block. Your current code is dangerous code.

Comment: Also, don't have Login extend Application as they are two completely different types of classes, one involving database connections, the other gui creation, and you don't want to mix the two as you're doing.

Comment: Thank you.. but is there any chance you also managed to find the reason i get an empty frame? I can add the code for the Main Menu.. but i dont think the problem is there

Comment: Again, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Ok, i will add Main screen, please take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainScreen **extends** JFrame unnecessarily. And so when you create a MainStream object, you create and display **two** JFrames, one that **is** the MainStream object and one that is created by the MainStream object. But more importantly, your classes are too complex and not self contained making it difficult to test them in isolation. Consider re-coding this using [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design principles. This will make your code much easier to debug and to enhance.

---

Change

```
  login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // .... etc...

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
        frame.dispose();

        MainScreen s = new MainScreen();
        s.setVisible(true);
     }
```

to

```
  login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // .... etc...

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
        frame.dispose();

        MainScreen s = new MainScreen();
        // !!  s.setVisible(true);  // don't call this!
     }
```

And don't have MainScreen extend JFrame.

There are a **lot** of other problems with your code, but this is the cause of your current bug.

Other issues:

- Ignoring exceptions. Read the exception tutorial so you won't be flying blind.
- Mixing database code with GUI code. Try to keep them in separate testable units.
- Extending JFrame unnecessarily. You almost never need or want to do this.
- Swapping JFrames where you should be showing a single stable JFrame for the most part and swap JPanel views.
- callling `setVisible(true)` on your JFrames **before** adding all components to them. This can cause creation of empty JFrames. Always call setVisible(true) **after** adding components.

---

Simplified test program to show that my suggestions work:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Login();
   }
}

class Login {
   private JFrame frame;// frame of the interface
   private JButton login = new JButton("Login");
   private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

   public Login() {
      makeFrame();
   }

   private void makeFrame() {
      frame = new JFrame("Login");
      frame.setSize(300, 200);
      // !! frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.add(panel);
      panel.add(login);
      login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
            frame.dispose();
            MainScreen s = new MainScreen();
            // s.setVisible(true); // !! get rid of
         }
      });
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class MainScreen {
   private JFrame frame;// frame of the interface
   private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel left = new JPanel();
   private JPanel center = new JPanel();
   private JPanel top = new JPanel();
   private JButton approve = new JButton("Approve");
   private JButton review = new JButton("Review");
   private JButton employmentCreate = new JButton("Create/Modify");
   private JLabel PR = new JLabel("Personal Records");
   private JLabel ER = new JLabel("Employment Records");
   private JLabel PerR = new JLabel("Perform Review");
   private JLabel AR = new JLabel("Approve Records");
   private JLabel news = new JLabel("There are no news");
   private JLabel empty = new JLabel();
   private JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
   private JButton personalCreate = new JButton("Create/Modify");
   private JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Welcome:");
   private JLabel userLbl = new JLabel("USERNAME GOES HERE");

   public MainScreen() {
      makeFrame();
   }

   private void makeFrame() {
      frame = new JFrame("Main Screen");
      frame.setSize(650, 550);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      // frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.add(panel);
      panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      top.add(welcome);
      top.add(userLbl);
      panel.add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
      left.add(news);
      panel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
      center.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
      center.add(PR);
      center.add(personalCreate);
      personalCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispose();
         }
      });
      center.add(ER);
      center.add(employmentCreate);
      employmentCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispose();
         }
      });
      center.add(PerR);
      center.add(review);
      center.add(AR);
      center.add(approve);
      center.add(empty);
      center.add(logout);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Um... If i dont extend JFrame i canot setVisible(true); get an erro says counds find symbol

Comment: @user3507763: you don't want to set MainScreen to visible, just the JFrame that it holds.

Comment: I dont know how to do that.. i looked all over the Internet, and everywhere it only shows this method.. can you please give me an example.

Comment: @user3507763: But you already do that. That's why you're seeing two windows and not one. Again, you don't need to have MainStream extend JFrame and shouldn't set it visible.

Comment: as for re-doing it.. this is my first time doing something like this with GUI.. this is more of a practice.. i will write a few better ones.. my goal right now it to make at least a working application with database connection.

Comment: You would do well to get a decent book on OOPs programming and Java and going through that first. The lessons learned will prove invaluable and will make programming complex stuff like this *much* easier. You're currently putting the cart before the horse -- trying to code complex Swing/database GUI's before understanding Java basics such as exceptions.... not good.

Comment: I understand what you are telling me.. but how do i point at just the JFrame ?

Comment: **You're already doing that**. Again you should **not call `setVisible()` on MainScreen**.

Comment: Again, make MainScreen not extend JFrame and don't call `s.setVisible()`.

Comment: then what do i call? when i remove set visible from either mainFrame  or login it just stop showing the other window and when it doesnt extend i just get errors

Comment: Ok, it does open it.. but now everything is gone

Comment: @user3507763: because you're calling `setVisible(true)` before adding components to your JFrame. Please see edit to answer including simplified code. But seriously read through a book and the Swing tutorials soon. Else you're in for a lot of frustration (and so are we).

Comment: Oh, thank you for the edit.. but i figured it out :) i like learning from experience.. and yes, i am currently reading 2 books and watching tutorials :)

Comment: the problem wasnt with setVisible.. i removed that.. but the it was just launching empty Jframe.. now i fixed the problem

Comment: Your Edit does look a lot cleaner then mine, thank you again.

Comment: Any chance you happen to also know how to make getting data from database work? I looked at the book and a few tutorials.. made a connection.. but when i try pulling String data using .getString() i keep on getting errors that i cannot do it.. and i been stuck on the whole thing for 2 days now